# fluuter the method validate was called on null

Tags: flutter

i have the following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building but i don't where is the error coming from

```
Form(
              key: formKeyEmail,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.03,
                    left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
                    right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05),
                child: TextFormField(
                  key: formKeyEmail,
                  autovalidate: isemail,
                  validator: (val) {
                    if (!EmailValidator.validate(val)) {
                      return "You have error in email";
                    }
                  },
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isemail = true;
                      dropdownforgotpassword = 0;
                      if (isemail) dropdownforgotpassword = 1;
                      if (ispassword) dropdownforgotpassword++;
                    });
                  },
                  onChanged: (String val) {
                    if (isemail) _email = val;
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Email : email@domain.com',
                    isDense: true,
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0))),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),

Form(
              key: formKeyPassword,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.03,
                    left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
                    right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05),
                child: TextFormField(
                  key: formKeyPassword,
                  autovalidate: ispassword,
                  obscureText: _obs,
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      ispassword = true;
                      dropdownforgotpassword = 0;
                      if (isemail) dropdownforgotpassword = 1;
                      if (ispassword) dropdownforgotpassword++;
                    });
                  },
                  onChanged: (String val) {
                    if (ispassword) _password = val;
                  },
                  validator: (val) {
                    if (val.length < 7) {
                      return 'Password is too short';
                    }
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Passowrd : ***************',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                    prefixIcon: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _obs = !_obs;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.visibility_off,
                        size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.06,
                      ),
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0))),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Can you also post the code of your `EmailValidator` class, please?

Comment: my problem was i am using the key in the form and in the textformfield problem solved.
the program crashed when i am using key in multiple widgets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
please remove `key: formKeyEmail` and `key: formKeyPassword` in `TextFormField`

code snippet

```
child: TextFormField(
              //key: formKeyEmail, 
...
child: TextFormField(
              //key: formKeyPassword,
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  final formKeyEmail = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final formKeyPassword = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  bool isemail = false;
  bool ispassword = false;
  String _email = "";
  String _password = "";
  bool _obs = true;
  int dropdownforgotpassword = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Form(
              key: formKeyEmail,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.03,
                    left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
                    right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05),
                child: TextFormField(
                  //key: formKeyEmail,
                  autovalidate: isemail,
                  validator: (val) {
                    /*if (!EmailValidator.validate(val)) {
                      return "You have error in email";
                    }*/
                  },
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isemail = true;
                      dropdownforgotpassword = 0;
                      if (isemail) dropdownforgotpassword = 1;
                      if (ispassword) dropdownforgotpassword++;
                    });
                  },
                  onChanged: (String val) {
                    if (isemail) _email = val;
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Email : email@domain.com',
                    isDense: true,
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0))),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Form(
              key: formKeyPassword,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.03,
                    left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
                    right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05),
                child: TextFormField(
                  //key: formKeyPassword,
                  autovalidate: ispassword,
                  obscureText: _obs,
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      ispassword = true;
                      dropdownforgotpassword = 0;
                      if (isemail) dropdownforgotpassword = 1;
                      if (ispassword) dropdownforgotpassword++;
                    });
                  },
                  onChanged: (String val) {
                    if (ispassword) _password = val;
                  },
                  validator: (val) {
                    if (val.length < 7) {
                      return 'Password is too short';
                    }
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Passowrd : ***************',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                    prefixIcon: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _obs = !_obs;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.visibility_off,
                        size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.06,
                      ),
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0))),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```